# Epson printer XP-445 does not print pdf files after upgrading to 19.10

Tags: pdf

After upgrading from 19.4 to 19.10 everything works fine. The printer can print a testpage, and no problems with textfiles. But it will not print PDF files, E-mail messages or output from other programs.The printrequest seems to complete, the request is removed from the printque. But nothing is printed